# Can't access external variables inside events.load method in react-native-highcharts

Tags: javascript, react-native, highcharts

I want to access all the high *chart APIs* outside the scope, I tried `ref={'chart' }` but didn't help, I am getting all the props via ref but not other functions

for the example, how to use below statements outside of the scope like in `componentDidMount(`) ( ie. `this.series[0]` is not available outside the scope)

```
var series = this.series[0];
setInterval(function () {
var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
y = Math.random();
series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Using arrow function may help you to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Piyush can u share me an example where I have to put arrow function?

Answer (score 1):

React Native uses WebView to create the chart so you cannot have to access to internal methods etc. You can communicate between two layers by messages only.

As a result you need to use `chart.update` only.

Comment: I want to update chart using socket data in 
```<ChartView style={{height:300}} config={conf} options={options}></ChartView>```
I have data from socket in the state variable now I am not able to update chart points using this data can you please help me is there any way to use state data inside chart scope  as you told its not possible to use internal methods outside the scope